# How to write UPDATE left joined multiple tables query(MySQL) using sqlalchemy core?

Tags: sqlalchemy

How to write the following sql with sqlalchemy core?

```
update t1 left join t2 on t1.event_date=t2.event_date set t1.sales=coalesce(t2.sales,0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following code in the Python console:

```
Python 3.8.2 (default, May  6 2020, 10:53:18) 
[Clang 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlalchemy
>>> print(sqlalchemy.__version__)
1.3.19
>>> from sqlalchemy import update, func, table, column, types
>>> from sqlalchemy.dialects import mysql
>>> mysql_dialect = mysql.dialect()
>>> c1 = column("id", types.Integer)
>>> c2 = column("event_date", types.Date)
>>> c3 = column("sales", types.Integer)
>>> t1 = table("t1", c1, c2, c3)
>>> c1b = column("id", types.Integer)
>>> c2b = column("event_date", types.Date)
>>> c3b = column("sales", types.Integer)
>>> t2 = table("t2", c1b, c2b, c3b)
>>> j = t1.outerjoin(t2, t1.c.event_date == t2.c.event_date)
>>> v = {t1.c.sales: func.coalesce(t2.c.sales, 0)}
>>> s = update(j).values(v)
>>> print(s.compile(dialect=mysql_dialect))
UPDATE t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.event_date = t2.event_date SET sales=coalesce(t2.sales, 0)
```

You see, the final result is very close to the perfect SQL: only the `t1.` prefix is missing in `SET sales=...` statement. I think this is a bug (or lack of feature) of SQLAlchemy 1.3.19. So I submitted an issue for that: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5617

It might work in some scenarios. But for your case, it will raise `ERROR: Column 'sales' in field list is ambiguous` when the SQL is run on the actual MySQL server, because the column name exists in both tables (this is what *ambiguous* means).

**Edited on 2020-09-30:**

zzzeek (Mike Bayer) has proposed [a workaround](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5617#issuecomment-700858768):

```
>>> s = update(j).values(v).where(t1.c.id > 0)
>>> print(s.compile(dialect=mysql_dialect))
UPDATE t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.event_date = t2.event_date SET t1.sales=coalesce(t2.sales, 0) WHERE t1.id > 0
```

Also he submitted a fix for this issue in the `master` branch and the `rel_1_3` branch. Hope that it will be fixed soon in the next 1.3.x minor release of SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/dml.html

```
users.update().values(
        name=select([addresses.c.email_address]).\
                where(addresses.c.user_id==users.c.id).\
                as_scalar()
    )
```

would give:

```
t1.update().values(
        sales=select([t2.c.sales]).\
             where(t2.c.event_date==t1.c.event_date).\
             as scalar()
     )
```

Left join and coalesce missing will check this if statement points in the right direction.

Comment: I test this statement and it generates sql like this: `update t1 set t1.sales=(select t2.sales from t2 where t1.event_date=t2.event_date)`  I wonder if these two sqls have any difference in performance.

Comment: Performence is a matter of the rdms ... other point is if it's correct enough because you wanted =0 when not matched.